# ¿Como capturar una variable tipo int en js?

Tags: javascript, html5

Bueno no sé si me di a entender correctamente, así que explico. 
Estoy trabajando con lo que es HTML, JS, PHP y MySQL. De momento mi único problema sería con JS. Estoy tratando de usar un if, para comparar 2 números, uno tiene que ser si o  si menor que el otro, si no pues salta un mensaje de error. (Un alert en este caso [Cantidad no valida, estas tratando de llevar mas de la cantidad existente (2)])
Todo iba bien, hasta el momento en que descubrí que no funcionaba del todo "bien" o bueno eso a mi parecer. Cuando decidí hacer la comparación de un numero de dos dígitos con uno de uno. Ejemplo:
2 es menor que 13, eso es obvio. Pero al parecer JS interpreta que 2 es mayor que 13 debido a que interpreta que 2 es mayor que 13 debido a que el 13 tiene un "1" y por ende JS termina dándome el mensaje de error del caso en donde el primer número es mayor que el segundo. La "solución" pues fue poner un 0 antes del 2 y ahí si JS, sabe que 2 es menor que 13.

```
var cantidadea = $('#xcant2').val();
if($('#xcanta2').val()> cantidadea)
{
    alert("Cantidad no valida, estas tratando de llevar mas de la cantidad existente (2)");
    return false;
}
else
{
    if($('#xcanta2').val()<0)
    {
        alert("Numero no valido. (Fila 2)");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        cantidadb2 = $('#xcanta2').val();
        coment2    = $('#xcoment2').val();
        modelo2    = $('#xvalmerc2').val();
        cantidade2 = $('#xcant2').val();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otra opción que puedes hacer es usar la función parseFloat(variable) que devuelve una cadena (string) en numero flotante.

Ejemplo:

```
var cantidadea = parseFloat($('#xcant2').val());

if(parseFloat($('#xcanta2').val()) > cantidadea)
{
     alert("Cantidad no valida, estas tratando de llevar mas de la cantidad existente (2)");
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Oh ya, utilizado parseFloat, el editor de autocompletado me sugirio parseInt y creo que para fines mas practicos utilizare ese. Agradezco mucho tu sugerencia.

Answer (score 1):

Los inputs siempre guardan valores de tipo texto, por tanto tienes que convertirlos primero a número. Una forma sencilla de hacerlo es, simplemente, poner un signo + delante:

```js
let v1=$('#campo1').val();
let v2=$('#campo2').val();

console.log('Como texto',v1+v2);
let resultado=+v1 + +v2;
console.log('como números', resultado);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="campo1" value="10">
<input id="campo2" value="12">
```